# MySQL Prepared statements - conditional statement to control execute

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to understand how best to use prepared statements to improve the response time on one or two of my queries. I have read a number of posts here and have been experimenting.

I would like confirmation/clarification that my understanding is correct and that I am heading in the right direction - in particular I would like to know whether I can include an execute with a prepare and how to incorporate conditional statements inside a prepare.

I am wondering whether I should be making the conditional statements part of the mysqli code rather than the actual prepared statement and if so whether there is a performance cost in doing so.

**This code does not work:**

```
PREPARE get_Class_Session FROM
       "SELECT @COUNT:=COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT time_Table_Key,
                     date,
                     DATE_FORMAT(date, '%W') AS day,
                     slot,
                     class_Session 
        FROM `Time_Table` 
        WHERE (((date >=? && date <= ?) && DAYOFWEEK(date)=? && (slot >=? && slot <=?)) && class_Session ='0'))
                AS time_Table_Keys;
        IF @COUNT = '0' THEN
            EXECUTE update_Time_Table USING @start_Date, @end_Date, @day, @start_Time, @end_Time;
        END IF;
       ";
```

Answer (score 0):

To improve the response time of the query one have to analyse output of the `EXPLAIN query` statement and take action in order to elimitane filesorts and temporary table use as well as reducing number of rows examined.
Unfortunately, prepared statements can help with neither of these things.